# ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected number got char plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to write an SQL

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SOURCE_SYSTEM <> 'SHIELD' 
            THEN NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM)
        WHEN SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'SHIELD' AND UPPER(PRODUCT_NAME_EN) = 'CANCER' AND NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM) < 100000
            THEN 'LESS THAN 100K'
        ELSE 'OTHER' 
    END AS NEW_GROUP
FROM TABLE
```

I also tried the same code but with a little twist

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SOURCE_SYSTEM <> 'SHIELD' 
            THEN NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM)
        WHEN SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'SHIELD' AND UPPER(PRODUCT_NAME_EN) = 'CANCER' AND TO_NUMBER(NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM, PAYABLE_PREMIUM)) < 100000
            THEN 'LESS THAN 100K'
        ELSE 'OTHER' 
    END AS NEW_GROUP
FROM TABLE
```

The same error still appears:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: How can we guess without table structure with datatypes? Please, provide it.

Comment: My bad, source_system varchar2(50), nominal_premium number(22,2), payable_premium number(22,2), product_name_en varchar2(1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of differet types you have in the first "case-when" and "else" parts.

This returns a number:

```
THEN NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM)
```

whereas here you'll get a char:

```
THEN 'LESS THAN 100K'
```

The solution would be to convert number to a char:

```
NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM) -> to_char(NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM))
```

So, here's what I did in order to get rid of this error

```
with test_data(source_system, nominal_premium, payable_premium, product_name_en) as (
  select 'a', 1, 2, 'b' from dual
)

SELECT
CASE WHEN SOURCE_SYSTEM <> 'SHIELD' 
     THEN to_char(NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM))
     WHEN SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'SHIELD' AND upper(PRODUCT_NAME_EN) = 'CANCER' AND TO_NUMBER(NVL(NOMINAL_PREMIUM,PAYABLE_PREMIUM)) <100000
     THEN 'LESS THAN 100K'
     ELSE 'OTHER' END AS NEW_GROUP
FROM test_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems like won't fix the problem for me, the same error message still appears

Comment: @ThinhLe that's weird. I've updated the answer with the whole query. PLease check whether you're doing the same?

Comment: thank you so much! it works perfectly this time!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped